# even and odd number of clicks count in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have four divs in my html page something like this:
the working fiddle implementation is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GxaCK/3/

```
 <div class="first">
    <p> First </p>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    <p> Second </p>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    <p> Third </p>
    </div>
    <div class="fourth">
    <p> Fourth </p>
    </div>
```

and then the jquery like this:

```
$(function() {
    var firstCnt = 0,
        secondCnt = 0,
        thirdCnt = 0,
        fourthCnt = 0;
    $(".first").live("click", function(){
        firstCnt += 1;
        $(".first p").text(firstCnt);
    });

     $(".second").live("click", function(){
        secondCnt += 1;
        $(".second p").text(secondCnt);
    });

});
```

now given this, i can do firstCnt%2 to get if the div was clicked for even or the odd number of times.

I have the following doubt:
1. is this a goodway of implementation, in a project?
2. is there anything like even odd selector for clicks as well, [as exists in css3](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

Comment: I dont think there is an odd click tracker for mouse events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even odd..you can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). See updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GxaCK/4/).